# Is it possible to Switch template with a url variable? like Joomla TMPL=component switch

Tags: django, wagtail

Hi We've just been dumped with a Django / Wagtail install ( not complaining - just don't know the system yet! )

Was starting to have a look at the templates. is there a simple mechanism to switch off the chrome ( or parts of the template ) like you can with Joomla using the tmpl=component switch?

The use case is To be able to quickly pull content into other sites etc without menu items or footers. In my case I wanted to create popout modal links that would display content?

is there a simple way to do this? is it simply a case of adding something into the base.html template to switch things off?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.get_template()` method on the Page class to do this. [See the documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/pages.html?highlight=get_template#dynamically-choosing-the-template).

It might look like:

```
from django.template import loader, TemplateDoesNotExist

class BlogPage(Page):
    ...

    def get_template(self, request):
        custom_template = request.GET.get('template', None)
        if custom_template:
            try:
                loader.get_template(custom_template)
            except TemplateDoesNotExist:
                pass
            else:
                return custom_template
        return super().get_template(request)
```

Now you can view the page with a different template by visiting http://example.com/mypage?template=path/to/template.html